# Oracle 12c - how to see all partitions and sub-partitions for some table and number of records for each

Tags: sql, oracle, count, partitioning

I got to explore table 't1'.

How to see:

- All partitions and which column is being used for partitions
- All sub-partitions and which column is being used for sub-partitions
- Number of records for each partition and number of record for each sub-partition

This gives a good start but need more info (above):

```
select * from ALL_PART_TABLES where table_name = 't1'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check `ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS`, and `ALL_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS` - all the required columns are available .

Comment: Thanks. This is great info too about name of partitions and sub-partitions and how many sub-partitions are in each partition. How to see number of records in each partition and sub-partitions?

Comment: There is a `NUM_ROWS` column avilable.  To know the column details you can use `ALL_PART_KEY_COLUMNS`  and `ALL_SUBPART_KEY_COLUMNS`  . Refer This link : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin005.htm

Comment: Thanks. Last 2 tables are great for column details. One note - I saw NUM_ROWS column but is showing 'null' for all partitions/subpartitions. Do I need to run some analysis command or something else in order for this column to get populated with real numbers?

Comment: Do you need the exact number of rows or just rough values?

Comment: if num_rows is null it means the statistics have never been computed.
run : exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA_NAME','TABLE_NAME',granularity=>'ALL');

Answer (score 1):

The below query gives the number of rows in SUBPARTITION

```
select num_rows, PARTITION_NAME , SUBPARTITION_NAME 
  FROM ALL_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS
where table_name = 'yourtable';
```

The below query gives the number of rows in PARTITION and also the number of sub partitions.

```
select num_rows, PARTITION_NAME, SUBPARTITION_COUNT     
  FROM ALL_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS
where table_name = 'yourtable';
```

Comment: NUM_ROWS column is showing 'null' for all partitions/subpartitions. Do I need to run some analysis command or something else in order for this column to get populated with real numbers?

Comment: You have to Analyze the table for the num_rows toshow up

Comment: Nowadays you should not use `ANALYZE` anymore. Use [DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm#ARPLS68582) instead.

Comment: @Valli - No no no. ANALYZE has been deprecated for stats gathering for  more than a decade. Always use DBMS_STATS package to gather statistics.